# Ubuntu broken - How to access /home/username/.profile

Tags: boot, 13.04

I made a mistake while I was changing /home/username/.profile file. Now I can't access my user session, I can only use guest session. How can I access that file so I can fix it. I already tried using root and nano, but I got error that system is read only, although I used sudo. I tried booting from Live CD but I can't access my home folder, I only get home folder from live session. Please help.

Comment: Can you copy the file using `mv` then change its permissions, and edit it (using sudo all the way) then replace the original?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the permissions for `.profile` before trying to edit the file itself?

`sudo chmod 740 /home/username/.profile`, then edit it.

Alternatively, if using `vim` to edit, you could try using the command `:w!` instead of `:w` to try and override the read-only flag.

Comment: I tried using chmod but I get message "can't access .../username/tty, ... something ... is read only ". btw I misspelled PATH variable in .profile file, now I have to type full paths to all commands. for example to use sudo I have to type /usr/bin/sudo etc